# Getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" every time I try to run `watch` with `nvidia-smi`

Tags: watch

I'm currently using GPUs on an Ubuntu server to run machine learning models. I often like to use the `watch` command in order to monitor the GPU statuses like `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi`. It usually works fine, but I noticed that for one of the servers I get the error:

```
watch: /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by watch)
watch: /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by watch)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get install libncursesw6` and get `libncursesw6 is already the newest version (6.2-0ubuntu2).`.

Is there anything else I can do to fix this error?

#### Edit

The output of `lddtree $PATH_TO_WATCH` is:

```
watch => /usr/bin/watch (interpreter => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
    libncursesw.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6
        libtinfow.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/./libtinfow.so.6
    libtinfo.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libtinfo.so.6
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: What does *lddtree path_to_watch* tell ?

Comment: Also, does `watch` work with any other command? What happens if you run something like `watch ls`?

Comment: @MC68020 Unfortunately I don't have `lddtree` installed so I can't answer your question.

Comment: @terdon The same error happens when I run `watch ls`. :(

Comment: On my system (not ubuntu) *watch* comes with the *procps* package. You could try re-installing it.

Comment: @MC68020 I downloaded the `pax-utils` which enabled the `lddtree` command. I'll edit the output in the OP.

Comment: @MC68020 Also, when I try to install `procps` it says that the newest version (2:3.3.16-1ubuntu2.3) is already installed.

Comment: OK, all this appears perfectly fine to me. BTW your process is segfaulting.  I doubt this is immediately linked to the inability to find information version. Any info available in dmesg about that segfault ? (trace dump…)

Comment: I get this error on all apps requiring libncursesw.so.6 in Ubuntu 22.04. Running them as root seems to fix the issue, which is unacceptable, but I haven't figured out what the offending (permission?) issue is.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that not only did the `watch` command cause this, but `htop` was also causing this error. An old coworker of mine managed to help me out by telling me that I had to run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6 /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6
```

I guess there was a conflict between a previous library and the symbolic link? If anyone has a better and more comprehensive understanding of this, please feel free to edit my answer.